# ¿como realizar una operación basado en la relación de un modelo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Tengo esta tabla en la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna `movement_type_id` es una relación donde el id 1 es igual a entrada y el 4 a salida y la columna `article_id` es otra relación donde el id 1 es un articulo.

Lo que quiero hacer es que, dependiendo del valor de `movement_type_id`, si es entrada me sume y si es salida me reste y me muestre en este caso un `amount` de 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu modelo se llame `Movement` y quisieras obtener el total (i.e. entradas - salidas) del artículo `1`, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
entradas = Movement.where(movement_type_id: 1, article_id: 1).sum(:amount)
salidas  = Movement.where(movement_type_id: 4, article_id: 1).sum(:amount)

total = entradas - salidas
```

---

El mejor lugar para poner este código es el mismo modelo, utilizando dos métodos para evitar repetición de código; por ejemplo:

```
class Movement < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def self.type_total(type, article)
    where(movement_type_id: type, article_id: article).sum(:amount)
  end

  def self.total(article)
    type_total(1, article) - type_total(4, article)
  end
end
```

Luego en tu controlador simplemente llamarías al método `total`:

```
@total = Movement.total(1)
```

Comment: muchas gracias tu respuesta me fue de gran ayuda